# How do I calculate GF(2) (Galois Field) without using a tool?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I am stuck and can't find anything on Google or SO. I have:

`1+1+1+0` and I am asked to calculate the *answer* over `GF(2)`.

My question: *what* answer?

I have no clue what to do. Can someone help me by telling me what I should do? Where do I start? Making an addition table? I honestly have no idea what they are asking or what is being expected.

Comment: The sum, I guess. Use that $GF(2)$ has characteristic $2$.

Comment: $GF(2)$ is the field of order $2$.  See e.g. [Finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field).

Comment: There is no definition and no, not using a book. Just an assignment. @Bernard: the sum? I have no idea what characteristic 2 means. We have just one slide that explains it and I can see an addition table, that's it. No theory, nothing. That's why I am struggling.

Comment: Ah, yes... well, 1+1 = 0. So I assume this is all XOR. I get that, but I don't get what I should do with it or how to assume I can use that? It's not stated in the assignment that I can use it.

Comment: I get 1+1 = 0, but the confusing part for me is the fact that we have 4 numbers. I don't know what "rules" we have when there are 4 numbers. What should I do? Just take the first two in parentheses? If so, why? I am trying to sort that out and that part is confusing, because I can't find info about it

Comment: The addition table alone tells you that addition is associative (though it’s tiresome to check this),  so order of summands is not important. You added left to right, but right to left would have been equally valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

> 1+1+1+0 is the same as doing: ((1+1)+1) + 0 =
>
> (1+1) = 0
>
> (0) + 1 = 1
>
> 1 + 0 = 1

That gives me 1 as my answer.